# How to fill MatBlazor SelectItem after an event?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am pretty new to MatBlazor. I am trying to fill a MatSelectItem with some options after something happens.

Initial locations = new LocnamesItem[] {};

```
<MatSelectItem Disabled="@(!locationvisible)" Label="Select Location" Value="@selectedLocation" Items="@locations" TValue="LocnamesItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>@context?.Locname - @context.Locdescr </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</MatSelectItem>
```

There is a login happening after which I fill the locations array with data.

```
        locationList = await LoginProcess.GetLocations(login.sysUserId);
        locations = locationList.ToArray();
        StateHasChanged();
```

Unfortunately the options don't appear after statehaschanged call.

Regular select control with options building works well with similar code.

Comment: Please, show the method signature of the code getting the locations...

Comment: Sorry, that's proprietary but I can attest that it returns a List<LocnamesItem>. When I debug and add a watch the array getting assigned to matselectitem contains data.

Comment: "proprietary ?" You definitely made me laugh heartily. Thank you...  Sorry, I've contacted my lawyer, and she has told me to  keep silent, and not to reveal any professional secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the learning curve. Adding the services.AddMatBlazor() at StartUp.cs resolved the issue.